# How can I draw this line figure with arrows using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-arrows

I need this figure drawn in TikZ for work. How do I do it?

[image: I need this]

So far, I have:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=2cm, font=\sffamily\small]

\draw[->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0) node[below] {$$};


\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4} \draw (\i,1mm) -- (\i,-1mm) node[below] {\i}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the unequal spacing and the displacement of the arrows intended?

Comment: I did it with paint. The distance of the nodes (1,2,3 ..) is the same. Sorry

Comment: Welcome to Tex SE. Have you searched the site for similar drawings to replicate?

Comment: I don't know the type of  latex is this.

Comment: could you post a MWE of the code you already wrote trying to achieve this?

Comment: Okey, I put in description

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here, without the unequal spacing and displaced arrows, but with TikZ.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,
  down arrow/.style = {
    single arrow, draw,
    minimum height=2.5em,
    transform shape,
    rotate=-90,
  }]
  \draw (0,0) -- (10,0);
  \foreach \i in {1,...,9}
    \draw (\i,0.3) -- (\i,-0.3) node[below] {\i};
  \foreach \i in {1,2,4,6,7,9}
    \node[down arrow] at (\i,1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]